# How to prevent zsh from expanding history when space bar is pressed?

Tags: command-line, zsh, history

I would like to use the expansion `mv 'foo bar' !#:1:s^\ ^-^` to produce the command `mv 'foo bar' 'foo-bar'`. However when I press the space bar, zsh assumes I've finished typing the expansion, leaving me with `mv 'foo bar' !#:1:s^\` which yields `mv 'foo bar' 'foobar'`.

I can circumvent this behavior by typing `mv 'foo bar' !#:1:s^\^-^` and then backtracking with the arrow keys to obtain `mv 'foo bar' !#:1:s^\ ^-^`, but that defeats the purpose.

How can I just turn off the expand-on-spacebar behavior? I suppose my desired behavior is to leave the command un-expanded until I press Enter. I didn't find anything on this in the manpage for `zshexpn`.

Edit: I've found that I can type `mv 'foo bar' !{#:1:s^\ ^-^}`, which holds off the expansion until the `}` is typed. But the question of how to prevent the expand-on-spacebar behavior stands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you have bound the space key to `magic-space`, because the [introduction to *zsh*](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Intro/intro_11.html) explains:

> If you bind space to magic-space, then csh-style history expansion is done on the line whenever you press the space bar.

So, either remove the line

```
bindkey " " magic-space
```

from your config. Or (if you are using some pre-defined config files like *d'oh-my-zsh*) make sure that the following command is executed after all other key bindings:

```
bindkey " " self-insert
```

Comment: I use Prezto. It turns out this was set in the "editor" module, in line 271 of the file `.zprezto/modules/editor/init.zsh`. I created a new "personal" branch by doing `cd ~/.zprezto && git checkout -b personal. I commented out the line and then `git commit`-ed the change, so the original Prezto configuration stays untouched.

Comment: Also, running `bindkey` with no arguments dumps the list of bound keys to stdout.